# Update Grand Total based on Discount/Points

Tags: cart, discount, grand-total, magento-1.9.3.3

I am using magento 1.9.3.3 version.
I have Customised Reward Points Extension.

In that i need to update Checkout cart Grand Total price while updating the cart based on Discount/Offer applied.(Attached Screenshot).

I used observer `sales_quote_save_after` with following code:

`$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->collectTotals()->save();`

But site is not working after this code inserted.

How to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Hi! "But site is not working after this code inserted." - it means that you get error? Can you share error text?

Comment: Hi Saravanan, 
I also have to create the same module(custom rewards redeem). can you please share your code with me or else please let me know how you do it. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is worked when i used `checkout_cart_save_after` event.